# Where does the comma go?

Tags: commas

This is my sentence.

> Religions assert things as fact.

Now I want to modify the object "things" with this phrase "that are not evidently true".

I know I could write it like this:

> Religions assert things that are not evidently true as facts.

But if I want to place the phrase at the end of the sentence like this :

> Religions assert things as facts that are not evidently true.

Would I need a comma between "facts" and "that"? Because if I don't use the comma, I feel that the phrase is modifying the word "facts", which is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: You don't need a comma. Both versions mean the same thing. In fact, if you *used* a comma, you'd end up with the interpretation you *don't* want: *Religions assert things, as [because] facts are not evidently true.*

Answer (score -2):

First sentence is correct.

In the second one you should switch to

> Religions assert things which are not evidently true as facts.

In the third example you can use:

> Religions assert things as facts altough they are not evidently true.